# Difference between `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter##word}`?

Tags: bash

According to `man bash`:

> ```
> ${parameter#word}  
> ${parameter##word}
>     Remove matching prefix pattern. The word is expanded to produce a
>     pattern just as in pathname expansion, and matched against the
>     expanded value of parameter using the rules described under Pattern
>     Matching below. If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of
>     parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
>     parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ``#'' case) or the
>     longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted. If parameter is
>     @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each positional
>     parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If
>     parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or *, the pattern
>     removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn,
>     and the expansion is the resultant list.
> ```

Somehow, I don't manage to find a situation that gives different results between `${parameter#word}` and `${parameter##word}`.

I am looking for situations that would illustrate the different behaviours between the two syntaxes. And incidentally, what would be a *shortest matching pattern* and what would be a *longest matching pattern*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example may be more illustrative

```bsh
$ parameter="This is a sentence with many words. Some of the words appear more than once. Oh, my word!"
$ echo "${parameter#*word}"
s. Some of the words appear more than once. Oh, my word!
$ echo "${parameter##*word}"
!
```

So:

- `${parameter#pattern}` removes the *shortest* match of the pattern
- `${parameter##pattern}` removes the *longest* match of the pattern

There are also `${parameter%pattern}` and `${parameter%pattern}` that match the pattern at the *end* of the string. I remember the difference because <kbd>#</kbd> appears *before* <kbd>%</kbd> on a (US) keyboard.

Comment: Unfortunately, on a german keyboard this hint does not work. I **always** have to look it up ...

Comment: Ah! I would have expected a minimal match of '\*word' to be with just 'word', which of course is not a match because the string doesn't start with 'word'. However 'This' is indeed the minimal match obtained with 'This\*' as a pattern... Nicely illustrative, thank you. Somehow I couldn't wrap my mind around the process from just reading the man page. But now that I know what it explains it all makes sense. Btw, the keyboard hint works on a French keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this example:

```
$ INT=00011
$ echo "${INT#*0}"
0011
$ echo "${INT##*0}"
11
```

Here, we first assign the string "00011" to the variable 'INT', then we output the result of the parameter expansion performed by either `${parameter#word}` or `${parameter##word}` with 'INT' as the parameter and '*0' as the word pattern.

The *minimal [prefix] match* of '*0' with the parameter is just '0', whereas the *maximal [prefix] match* is '000'.

Comment: It'd be helpful to others in the future to add some explanation of your example.